# Android WiFiDirectDemo p2p connection working as server-client

Tags: android, wifi, p2p

I test WiFiDirectDemo that is available as Android example, it works as it should. Now this app work as Server-Client. What I want is to work as p2p. Both devices should be able to receive and send data.
I don't know how to achieve communication  in both ways?

Any direction in the right  way would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

Comment: @minafawzy This is used in this example, that I tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that both devices serves as client and server. And sending messages between is simple, Developer should just implement system for checking and acknowledgment.